# What is an efficient alternative to cross join two large tables to get running total?

Tags: sql, hive, cumulative-sum, cross-join

I have 2 tables whose schema is as follows:
table1

```
event_dt
6/30/2018
7/1/2018
7/2/2018
7/3/2018
7/4/2018
7/5/2018
7/6/2018
7/7/2018
7/8/2018
7/9/2018
7/10/2018
```

table:2

```
event_dt    time(in seconds)
7/7/2018     144 
7/8/2018     63 
7/1/2018     47 
7/8/2018     81 
7/9/2018     263 
7/7/2018     119 
7/8/2018     130 
7/9/2018     206 
7/5/2018     134 
7/1/2018     140
```

For each date in table 1 i want to find the cumulative sum of time upto that date   .So i used a cross join to get the output using the following code:

```
select t1.event_dt, sum(t2.time)
from yp1 t1 cross join yp2 t2
where t1.event_dt>=t2.event_dt
group by t1.event_dt
```

Using this query i was able to get the cumulative running total for each date in table 1 as long as there is an event before that day. For example first event date is 07/01/2018 but the first date in table1 is 06/30/2018 so in the final output 6/30/2018 wont be present.

The problem with this method is the cross join is taking too long, i have millions of records since an observation is taken every 6 seconds. SO is there a way to get the same results without a cross join or for that matter any way which is more efficient.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use SQL's cumulative sum function:

```
select event_dt, running_time
from (select event_dt, time, sum(time) over (order by event_dt) as running_time
      from ((select event_dt, null as time
             from t1
            ) union all
            (select event_dt, time
             from t2
            ) 
           ) tt
     ) tt
where time is null;
```

Comment: The last where condition is not working. I came up with an alternative using left join and then getting the running total. Involves the same number of steps.

Comment: @Raj . . . This should be much more efficient than a `join`/`group by`.

Comment: Hi, the code is throwing an error stating `time` column in not present. In the second outer "tt" sub-query while calculating the running time there is only the new runnint total right, so the where condition outside wont be able to filter on "time" field, or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @Raj . . . It is very easily included in the subquery.